# suggested edit approvals

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

I have been doing some edit to posts and sometimes when I have one rejected I don't know why. I don't know yet how many approvals or rejects needed for accepting or not an edit done to a post. How many people must vote for the same edit?

Comment: Look at the 'activity' tab on your profile page, filter on 'suggestions'. You'll see a 'suggested' link on each suggestion, which allows you to review the reviews.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, 3 reviews are needed, on other sites, only 2.

Comment: In particular, don't just search for "Thanks in advance" within questions and remove that, touching nothing else that's wrong with the question. Take some more time and provide a more substantial edit that improves the question. A few of your edits were rejected as being too minor for that reason.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Martijn's comment, here is your [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1696979/mram888?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) you can check all your suggested edit detail from the link.

You can find following image like,

[image]

When you will click on suggested edit link ( in red circle ) you can find the actual detail as follows,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My personal view: you seem to just remove "Thanks in advance" from posts. This *might* pass for recent posts, but for older posts you have to improve other things if you want it approved.

Personally I will almost always reject such a minor edit unless it also change other things in the post. The reason is that searching for "thanks in advance" then suggesting to remove it without any further effort smells of plain badge hunting and/or rep farming and not really improving anything.

Comment: The age of the post shouldn't matter all.

Comment: @Servy it matters to me, since there is less point in bumping old posts to the front, unless there is real improvement.

Comment: My point is that this shouldn't be done for *either* old or new posts, not that it should be done for both.

Comment: @Servy I know and personally I will also reject for both, but from long experience doing it on new posts have better "chances" to pass.

Comment: What should be approved and what people actually approved are so far removed that I don't even bother comparing them anymore.  Just removing "thanks in advance" and nothing else shouldn't be accepted; it is "too minor".

Comment: @Servy can't agree more, but like I said earlier today there are no rules for this. (just yet)